# How to make a svg animation effect scale from bottom to top

Tags: animation, svg, scale, effects

I'm just starting to deal with Svg, so Im not really aware how to deal with all the effect,

I'm looking to do an small effect animation, exactly like this website: http://www.resanova.fr/

The idea would be to scale my svg image from the bottom to the top like you can see on this website.

I've try the following:

```
<animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                attributeName="transform"
                type="scale"
                from="0"
                to="1"
                dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" />
```

But without success, that just does a normal scale effect instead of the bottom to top . . ..

--EDIT--

Please fidn attach my svg on jsfiddle if it helps :)

https://jsfiddle.net/v3p9gLjx/3/

Comment: SVG scales around the origin. If you want it to scale from bottom to top, make the origin the bottom.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the indication, can you be a bit more precise by any chance ? Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Provide some markup that you're trying to animate.

Comment: Hi, I''ve edit my question with my svg if it helps . . .thank you for all your help !!!